# iphone sdk \Uxxx to utf-8

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios5, utf-8

I am working on a iphone app where I send user informations via SOAP to my server, where I store them in my database as UTF-8 strings.

The problem is, that when the server receives the strings they are sent as Unicode formatted in the form e.g. \U00fc which supposed to be a 'ü'.
the string containing '\U00fc' is stored correctly in the database. but when I read the database I get only 'U00fc' the \ is gone...

But also for better read option I would actually like to convert the '\U00fc' into a 'ü' store it to the database and then when reading the database I would convert it back for the iPhone.

I just couldn't find any functions in PHP that does this... I am pretty sure something like this must exist somewhere already, not that I have to re-implement the whole unicode table...

if you know any suggestions I would be glad if you could help me.

Comment: You seem to be sending JSON data. Use `json_decode()` to turn those characters back into proper UTF-8 chars

Comment: No it is not json... when I send the string Müller it actually sends M\U00fcller. iOS is translating the ü into \U00fc as this table shows the signs: http://javathreads.de/2008/10/die-wichtigsten-utf-8unicode-sonderzeichen-fuer-die-entwicklung-mit-facelets/

Comment: HI Pekka, thanks for the hint... actually the string is not json encoded but I tried with json_decode() function which works when I use: json_decode('"M\u00fcller"') but the problem is that I get: M\U00fcller (big U)... when I then use: json_decode('"M\U00fcller"') I get null... if I use: strtolower('M\U00fcller') it will work, but then the whole string is lowercase...

Comment: Right, I see. It's not exactly the same encoding then, using `json_decode` probably won't be the best idea. Hmm, if you could find out what this specific encoding method is called, you could ask / look for decoding methods for it in PHP. I have seen questions about this around on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input insists on upper case `\U`, you could fix it with this:

```
<?php
header( "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

function fixEscapeSequence( $str ) {
    return preg_replace( '/\\\U([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/', '\u$1', $str );
}

echo json_decode(fixEscapeSequence('"M\U00FCller"'));
//Müller
```

Or all wrapped in one:

```
function uToUTF8( $str ) {
    $needle = array( "\\", '"');
    $repl = array( "\\\\", '\\"' );
    $str = str_replace( $needle, $repl, $str );
    return json_decode( preg_replace( '/\\\\\\\U([a-f0-9]{4})/i', '\u$1', "\"{$str}\"" ) );
}



echo uToUTF8( 'M\u00FCller');
//Müller
echo uToUTF8( 'M\U00FCller');
//Müller
```

Comment: Hi Esailija, that's what I was thinkiong as well and tried to get the regex done.. but couldn't make it work. thank you very much for your suggestion! I think this is exactly what I will have to do. cheers

Comment: thank you so much for solution. The problem that I has is that our site is on php 5.2, so I cannot use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE. Anyway, awesome. Thanks again!